# ¿Cómo convertir "true" y "false" en sus valores booleanos?

Tags: python, csv

Necesito que una lista de bool llamado `DENUNCIADO ["true","false","true","false","false"]` convertirlo a un tipo `bool : [true,false,true]` para despues ponerlo en una condición donde me ejecute el siguiente código que se trata de sacar el porcentaje media del total dependiendo de 2 lista en este caso `s.Cuerpo[Aspecto fisico]` y `s.Denunciado [true:denunciado]` es decir  : calcula cuantas personas con aspectos fiscos `[gordo,musculoso,flaco]` fueron no `Denunciadas[false]` y sacar el porcentaje de cada aspecto

mi problema es que no necesito "true" o  "false" (en str) si no en bool y no se como poner la condicion para que me identifique el bool que creo convertí

```
def porcentaje (Doc):
    Datos2 = [s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if s.DENUNCIADO ] #
    ConvertidorBool = list(map(lambda ele: ele == "false", Datos2))
    Datos=[s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if ConvertidorBool == "false"] # condicion
    CC = {Ca: Datos.count(Ca)*100/1000 for Ca in Datos if Ca !=""}
    Contador = Counter(CC)
    Agrupador = Contador.items()
    Porcentaje = dict(Agrupador)
    Resultado= print("{}".format(Porcentaje))
    return Resultado
```

Comment: `[True if s =="true" else False for s in datos2]`

Comment: Mmm lo que podrías hacer es usar un for tradicional y sobreescribir el index de DENUNCIADO con true o false dependiendo el string, habría que ver el origen de los datos, porque si tienes un modelo definido puede ser que desde allí se resuelva.

Comment: @Christian entonces si hago : `Bool = [True if s =="true" else False for s in datos2]` y despues lo asigno a : `Datos=[s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if  Bool == "false"]` funcionaria no? ...voy a intentar

Comment: @Mr SaberHagen lo que hizo christian no?

Comment: @Christian Aún se puede reducir más: `[s=="true" for s in datos2]`

Comment: no funcion asi lo puse : Bool = [s=="true" for s in Datos2]
    Datos=[s.Cuerpo for s in Doc if Bool == False] y no sale : {}

Comment: No es así lo que se te ha dicho. La primera parte genera una lista de booleanos pero ¿qué pretendes con la segunda parte en la que asignas `Datos`? la comparación `Bool == False` no puede hacerse, porque `Bool` es una lista, no es un booleano. No sé si lo que estás intentando es lo mismo que se lograría con `Datos = [s.Cuerpo for s, ok in zip(Doc, Bool) if not ok]`

Comment: De todas formas este tipo de operaciones no suelen hacerse mediante bucles, sino mediante operadores Pandas, pero para poder mostrarte cómo sería necesitaría una muestra de tu dataframe (es decir, del csv).

Comment: 1)se que con Pandas es mejor pero obligatoriamente me toca sin ella, 2) ¿Qué pretendes con la segunda parte en la que asignas Datos? : al hacer str "false" en  Datos el código me filtra cuantas personas gordas , flacas fueron no denunciadas y del total saca un porcentaje de cada uno de los aspectos que esta en una lista [Cuerpo] ,la verdad no entiendo que debo  hacer para que me lo pase esos str a bool y que coja el false para ejecute el codigo Datos.

Comment: gracias por su ayuda ya solucione mi problema  :3